# Employ early bail-out in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab

There is a example for `Employ early bail-out` in this book ([http://www.amazon.com/Accelerating-MATLAB-Performance-speed-programs/dp/1482211297](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1482211297)) (@YairAltman). for speed improvement we can convert this code:

```
data = [];
newData = [];
outerIdx = 1;
while outerIdx <= 20
    outerIdx = outerIdx + 1;
    for innerIdx = -100 : 100
        if innerIdx == 0
            continue % skips to next innerIdx (=1)
        elseif outerIdx > 15
            break % skips to next outerIdx
        else
            data(end+1) = outerIdx/innerIdx;
            newData(end+1) = process(data);
        end
    end % for innerIdx
end % while outerIdx
```

to this code:

```
function bailableProcessing()
for outerIdx = 1 : 5
    middleIdx = 10
    while middleIdx <= 20
        middleIdx = middleIdx + 1;
        for innerIdx = -100 : 100
            data = outerIdx/innerIdx + middleIdx;
            if data == SOME_VALUE
                return
            else
                process(data);
            end
        end % for innerIdx
    end % while middleIdx
end % for outerIdx
end % bailableProcessing()
```

How we did this conversion? Why we have different `middleIdx` range in new code? Where is checking for `innerIdx` and `outerIdx` in new code? what is this new `data = outerIdx/innerIdx + middleIdx` calculation?

we have only this information for second code :

> We could place the code segment that should be bailed-out within a
>   dedicated function and return from the function when the bail-out
>   condition occurs.

Comment: It sure doesn't look like equivalent code.  I wouldn't work too hard on this.  Just try to understand the tip that you highlighted and move on.

Comment: Thank you for reply peter. What is tip of new code?

Comment: Take the inner portion that you're `breaking` out of, move it into a function, and use `return` instead of `break`.

Comment: The book's author @YairAltman is occasionally active on SO - perhaps this mention of his name will act as a bat-signal for an answer from him!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry that I did not clarify within the text that the second code segment is not a direct replacement of the first. If you reread the early bail-out section (3.1.3) perhaps you can see that it has two main parts:

The first part of the section (which includes the top code segment) illustrates the basic mechanism of using `break/continue` in order to bail-out from a complex processing loop, in order to save processing time in computing values that are not needed.

In contrast, the second part of the section deals with cases when we wish to break out of an ancestor loop that is not the direct parent loop. I mention in the text that there are three alternatives that we can use in this case, and the second code segment that you mentioned is one of them (the other alternatives are to use dedicated flags with `break/continue` and to use `try/catch` blocks). The three code segments that I provided in this second part of the section should all be equivalent to each other, but they are NOT equivalent to the code-segment at the top of the section.

Perhaps I should have clarified this in the text, or maybe I should have used the same example throughout. I will think about this for the second edition of the book (if and when it ever appears).

I have used a variant of these code segments in other sections of the book to illustrate various other aspects of performance speedups (for example, 3.1.4 & 3.1.6) - in all these cases the code segments are NOT equivalent to each other. They are merely used to illustrate the corresponding text.

I hope you like my book in general and think that it is useful. I would be grateful if you would place a positive feedback about it on Amazon ([direct link](https://www.amazon.com/review/create-review?ie=UTF8&asin=1482211297&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=283155&ref_=cm_cr_dp_wrt_summary&store=books#)).

p.s. - @SamRoberts was correct to surmise that mention of my name would act as a "bat-signal", attracting my attention :-)

[image: Accelerating MATLAB Performance book]

Comment: Thank you for answer Yair. I'm reading your book. I found some code errors that may help you for second edition. In the end of reading I can send them to your provided e-mail.

Comment: Thanks, that would be appreciated. I'll also add them to the book's online errata list. It was a very large and highly-technical book, so some errors/mistakes/typos were bound to enter the text...

Comment: @user2991243 - I am now editing the 2nd edition of my "Accelerating Matlab Performance" book. Please email me (altmany at gmail) your list of suggested fixes. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

it's all far more simple than you think!

> How we did this conversion?

Irrationally. Those two codes are *completely different*.

> Why we have different middleIdx range in new code?

Randomness. The point of the author is something different.

> Where is checking for innerIdx and outerIdx in new code?

dont need that, as it's not intended to be the same code.

> what is this new data = outerIdx/innerIdx + middleIdx calculation?

a random calculation as well as `data(end+1) = outerIdx/innerIdx;` in the original code.

i suppose the author wants to illustrate something far more profoundly: that if you wrap your code that does (possibly many) loops (fors/whiles, doesnt matter) inside a **function** and you issue a **return** statement if you somehow detect that you're done, it will result in an effectively "bailable" computation, e.g. the method that does the work returns earlier than it would normally do. that is illustrated here by the condition that checks on `data == SOME_VALUE`; you can have your favourite bailout condition there instead :-)

moreover, the keywords [`continue`/`break`] inside the first example are meant to illustrate that you can [skip the rest of/leave] the inner-most loop from whereever you call them. in principal, you can implement a bailout using these by e.g.

```
bailing = false;
for outer = 1:1000
   for inner = 1:1000
      if <somebailingcondition>
         bailing = true;
         break;
      else
         <do stuff>
      end
   end
   if bailing
     break;
   end
end
```

but that would be very clumsy as that "cascade" of breaks will need to be as long as you have nested loops and messes up the code.

i hope that could clarify your issues.